# Error using <allocators> header file on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, stl

I'm trying to use the [boolinq](http://code.google.com/p/boolinq/) code in my project and its failing because it uses the allocators header file which doesn't exist on my system. I'm using Ubuntu and all the other STL types are working. Does anyone know how i can fix this ?

Comment: Don't use that header. Find another replacement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such header in C++ standard. To be honest I have no idea where they got it from, because my Visual Studio (admittedly they are using newer version) does not have it either.

Comment that include out and you should see what symbol it misses. `std::allocator` is in `<memory>`. If it needs anything else, you'll have to find (possibly replacement for) it or disable it's use.